# Java: Example for unsafe publication

Tags: java, concurrency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java multi-threading & Safe Publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication)

I did not understand what unsafe publication is. Can anyone provide a simple example for unsafe publication and explain the adverse effect based on the example.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned as "Possible duplicate". Please reopen this.

Comment: that question is different. pls don't close

Comment: I was not able to find a good example "via simple Google search". Also, I think that most Java programmers are unaware of this. Kindly don't close. Don't deny the opportunity to learn from experts here.

Comment: Example - http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Sharing-Objects/Safe-Publication/

Comment: This question is in no way a duplicate. The moderators simply read the question title and are too lazy to read the details and figure out how well the responses answer the OP's question.