# Java: Is volatile / final required for reference to synchronized object?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

This seems a pretty basic issue, but I cannot find a clear confirmation.

Let's say I have a class properly synchronized in itself:

```
public class SyncClass {

   private int field;

   public synchronized void doSomething() {
       field = field * 2;
   }

   public synchronized void doSomethingElse() {
       field = field * 3;
   }
}
```

If I need to have a **reference** to an instance of that class, shared between threads, **I do still need to declare that instance volatile or final**, am I right? As in:

```
public class MainClass { // previously OuterClass

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {

        final SyncClass mySharedObject = new SyncClass();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mySharedObject.doSomething();
            }
       }).start();

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mySharedObject.doSomethingElse();
            }
       }).start();
    }
}
```

Or, if `mySharedObject` cannot be final, because its instantiation depends on some other conditions (interaction with GUI, info from socket, etc.), not known beforehand:

```
public class MainClass { // previously OuterClass

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {

        volatile SyncClass mySharedObject;

        Thread initThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            // just to represent that there are cases in which
            //   mySharedObject cannot be final
            // [...]
            // interaction with GUI, info from socket, etc.
            // on which instantation of mySharedObject depends

            if(whateverInfo)
                mySharedObject = new SyncClass();
            else
               mySharedObject = new SyncClass() {
                   public void someOtherThing() {
                     // ...
                   }
               }
            }
       });

       initThread.start();

       // This guarantees mySharedObject has been instantied in the
       //  past, but that still happened in ANOTHER thread
       initThread.join();

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mySharedObject.doSomething();
            }
       }).start();

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mySharedObject.doSomethingElse();
            }
       }).start();
    }
}
```

**Final or volatile are mandatory**, the fact that `MyClass` synchronizes the access to its own members, does NOT exempt to take care in ensuring that the reference is shared among threads. Is that right?

**Differences with** [Difference between volatile and synchronized in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java)

1- The referred question is about synchronized and volatile as alternatives, for the same field/variable, my question is about how to correctly use an already properly synchronized class (i.e. synchronized has been choosen), considering implications needed to be considered by the caller, possibly using volatile/final on a reference of an already synchronized class.

2- In other words, the referred question/answers are about locking/volatile THE SAME OBJECT, my question is: how can I be sure different threads actually SEE THE SAME OBJECT? BEFORE locking/accessing it.

When the first answer of referred question refers explicitly to a volatile reference, it's about an *immutable* object *without synchronization*. The second answer limits itself to primitive types. 
I DID find them useful (see below), but not complete enough to shed any doubts on the case I'm giving here.

3- The referred answers are very abstract and scholarly explanations to a very open question, with quite no code at all; as I stated in the introduction I need to a clear confirmation to actual code referring a specific, while quite common, issue. They're related, sure, but just as a text book is related to a specific problem. (I actually read it before opening this question, and find it useful, yet I still need to discuss a specific application.) If text books resolved all problems/doubts people may have applying them, we probably wouldn't need stackoverflow at all.

Consider that, in multithreading, you cannot "just try it out", you need a proper understanding and be sure of details, because race conditions can go right a thousand times and then go horribly wrong the thousand + 1 time.

Comment: If the field is only accessed from within synchronized blocks, there's no need for volatile. If you want a guarantee that the mySharedObject is the same one for the doSomthing* methods, it's safer to make it final. Making it volatile makes this quite fuzzy instead.

Comment: Is it `SyncClass` or `MyClass` ? You need to be consistent :)

Comment: But there are cases in which mySharedObject CANNOT be final, because its instantation may depend on various conditions: different constructors parameters or even differeent actual classes, extended from SyncClass.

Comment: @Arkantos Sorry, corrected.

Comment: This question does not look like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java.  The other question talks about the memory visibility of a single field.  This question is more complicated.  GozzoMan is asking whether synchronization that affects the visibility of fields _in_ some object O also affects a field somewhere else that is assigned a reference _to_ object O.  (P.S., The answer is No.  There is no relationship between fields in an object and other fields that refer to the object.)

Comment: @jameslarge I agree completely, not sure why the person decided to close it.  Don't think they even read this question compared to the other.

Comment: @GozzoMan do you still have any outstanding questions?

Comment: Note that Java does not allow the `volatile` keyword on local variables, in the way it is used on `mySharedObject` in your third example. It can only go on fields. Is your intention that `mySharedObject` should be a field on `MainClass`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you are right. It is necessary that you make access to the variable also thread-safe. You can do that either by making it `final` or `volatile`, or you ensure that all threads access that variable again inside a synchronous block. If you wouldn't do that, it might be that one thread 'sees' already the new value of the variable, but the other thread might still 'see' `null`, for example.

So regarding your example, you could sometimes get a `NullPointerException` when a thread accesses the `mySharedObject` variable. But this might only happen on multi-core machines with multiple caches.

**Java Memory Model**

The main point here is the Java Memory Model. It states a thread is only guaranteed to see a memory update of another thread if that update happens before the read of that state in the so-called *happens-before relation*. The happens-before relation can be enforced by using `final`, `volatile`, or `synchronized`. If you do not use any of these constructs a variable assignment by one thread is never guaranteed to be visible by any other thread.

You can think of threads to conceptually have local caches and as long as you do not enforce that caches of multiple threads are synchronized, a thread just reads and writes to its local cache. This might lead to the situation where two threads see completely different values when reading from the same field.

Note that there are some additional ways to enforce visibility of memory changes, for example, using static initializers. In addition, a newly created thread always sees the current memory of its parent thread, without further synchronization. So your example might even work without any synchronization, because the creation of your threads are somehow enforced to happen after the field has been initialized. *However* relying on such a subtle fact is very risky and can easily break if you later refactor your code without having that detail in mind. Further details about the happens-before relation are described (but hard to understand) in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html).

Comment: A lot of other answers don't seem to understand how synchronized works. Synchronized will synch the current thread's variables with main memory but does not guarantee that other threads' variables are synchronized. Unless you can GUARANTEE that other threads will hit a "synchronize", volatile should be used on variables that can be used across threads. In threaded programming it pays to be paranoid.

Comment: Sure, you should encapsulate the access to the variable behind a synchronized method and make the variable private to be on the safe side. I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Necreaux I have to completely disagree. Thread safety should be 100% ensured by design, not hoped for by sprinkling `volatile` everywhere you think you might need it. In Java, `volatile` has precise semantics and can certainly be part of such 100% assurance by design, but not by sprinkling it around out of paranoia.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this answer is correct for the third example, where `mySharedObject` is initialised on one of the new threads. There `final`, `volatile` or other means of synchronisation is required. But this answer is **not correct** for the first example, where `mySharedObject` is initialised on the main thread before `start` is called for the new threads. In that example `final` or `volatile` is not required. See [Radiodefs answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29130789/452775).

Answer (score 2):

> If I need to have a refence to an instance of that class, shared between threads, I do still need to declare that instance volatile or final, am I right?

Yes, you are right.  In this case you have two shared variables:

`private int field`

`private SyncClass mySharedObject`

Because of the way you have defined `SyncClass` any reference to a `SyncClass` will give you the most up to date value of that `SyncClass`.

If you don't synchronize the access to `mySharedObject` correctly (a non-final, non-volatile) field and you change the value of `mySharedObject` you may get a `mySharedObject` which is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the context of how this variable is shared.

Here is a simple example where it's fine:

```
class SimpleExample {
    private String myData;

    public void doSomething() {
        myData = "7";

        new Thread(() -> {
            // REQUIRED to print "7"
            // because Thread#start
            // mandates happens-before ordering.
            System.out.println(myData);
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Your given examples may fall under this case. [17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> - If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
> - A call to `start()` on a thread *happens-before* any actions in the started thread.

In other words if the assignment to `mySharedObject` takes place on the same thread that starts the new thread, the new thread is mandated to see the assignment regardless of synchronization.

However, if you expect, for example, that `init` could be called on a thread that is different from the one that calls `doSomething`, then you may have a race condition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final OuterClass myOuter = new OuterClass();

    Thread t1 = new Thread( () -> myOuter.init(true)    );
    Thread t2 = new Thread( () -> myOuter.doSomething() );

    t1.start(); // Does t1#run happen before t2#run? No guarantee.
    t2.start(); // t2#run could throw NullPointerException.
}
```

The fact that `SyncClass` has synchronized methods is completely irrelevant with respect to guaranteed state of the `mySharedObject` reference. Reading that reference is performed outside the synchronized block.

When in doubt, use `final` or `volatile`. Whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to keep in mind here for understanding:

1. Racing for your reference variable has no conceptual difference from that of a member field.
2. Sharing a reference variable requires careful handling of [safe publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication)

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory to use any of them but you should know about them if you want to write proper multi-threaded code.

**Final**

`final` means you cannot re-initialize that variable again, so when you say

```
final SyncClass mySharedObject = new SyncClass();
```

you cannot do the initialization of `mySharedObject` again in some other part of code like below

```
   mySharedObject = new SyncClass(); // throws compiler error
```

Even though you cannot re-assign `mySharedObject` reference to some other object, you can still update it's state (field counter variable) by calling methods on it because `field` is not final.

Synchronization and volatile are just constructs to ensure that any change to a shared mutable object (in this case updating a `field` counter) by one thread is visible to all other threads.

**Synchronization**

`synchronized` method means that any thread trying to invoke that method should acquire a lock on the object in which that method is defined.

So in your case, If thread-1 is trying to do `mySharedObject.doSomething()`, it will acquire lock on `mySharedObject` and thread-2 has to wait until thread-1 releases that lock on the same object to be able to do `mySharedObject.doSomethingElse()` i.e using Synchronization at any given point of time, only ONE thread will update the state of the object. At the end of the method, just before releasing the lock all the changes done by thread-1 are flushed to main memory so that thread-2 can work on the recent state.

**Volatile**

`volatile` on the other hand ensures read/write visibility to all the threads. Any read and write to volatile variable are always flushed to main memory.

If your `field` variable inside `SyncClass` is volatile, any update like `field++` by thread-1 is visible to thread-2 but I'm not sure how it applies to object references.

As volatile only guarantees visibility but not atomicity, it's possible that both thread-1 and thread-2 try to update `field` counter at the same time and the final updated value may not be proper.