# Java volatile semantics, JMM guarantees

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Please consider following code snippet.

```
public class Visibility {

    private volatile SomeData data;

    public static class SomeData {

        private int number;

        public SomeData(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        data = new SomeData(42);
    }

    public SomeData getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

If `number` field was final, any thread that sees `data` reference is not `null` (after other thread called `initialize`) is also guaranteed to see `number` field value as `42`.

Do we have the same guarantees for non final field?
In other words, is it possible for some thread to observe non-null
`data` reference, but `number` field as `0`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** possible for some thread to observe non-null data reference, but number field as 0.

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) of volatile:

> This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to
>   other threads. What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a
>   volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile,
>   **but also the side effects of the code that led up the change**.

So when you get a non-null `data`, it must have been successfully initiated, the `number` must be non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, it is possible to see a field in a partially constructed state if the field is not published in a safe manner. In the particular case of your question, the `volatile` keyword is a satisfactory form of safe publication. According to [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601):

> To publish an object safely, both the reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to other threads at the same time.
>   A properly constructed object can be safely published by:
>
> - Initializing an object reference from a static initializer.
> - Storing a reference to it into a volatile field.
> - Storing a reference to it into a final field.
> - Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a (synchronized) lock.

For more information, see the following:

- [Does a volatile reference really guarantee that the inner state of the object is visible to other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200870/does-a-volatile-reference-really-guarantee-that-the-inner-state-of-the-object-is)
- [Java multi-threading & Safe Publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication)
- [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)