# Understanding Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to understand whether this is thread safe. I believe it is, but someone recently brought into question the thread safety of this method.

Let's say I have some factory `FactoryA` that give us a class which implements the following interface:

```
public abstract class MyFactory {
    private ObjectA object;
    public void init(ObjectA object){
        _object = object;
    }
}
```

So, we have something like

```
public class FactoryA extends MyFactory {
    static final createFactoryClass(String name) {
        // ...ignorning safety checks for brevity
        return MY_MAP.get(name).newInstance();
    }
}
```

Now, I have some method in another class that takes the factory and gives back a map of possible classes:

```
public class OtherClass {
    private static FactoryA _factory = new FactoryA();
    private static final Map<String, SomeClass> MY_MAP = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, MyClass>()
    .put("foo", _factory.createFactoryClass("foo"));

    private SomeObject myMethod(ObjectA objectA, SomeObject someObject) {
        MY_MAP.get(someObject.getString()).init(objectA);
    }
}
```

The question is whether the `init` method is thread safe. The map is initialized only once, so even though it's stored in an immutable structure, if two threads call it with different `ObjectA`, is it possible for the wrong class to use the wrong `ObjectA`?

Can I just fix this possible problem by doing the following?

`private static synchronized myMethod(...) {}`

Comment: It's a bit confusing since in-code you are referencing to objects cross-class and type mismatching. But I think the real question lies in what you are doing in your `init` method?

Comment: Your `MyFactory.init` method, as given, is completely thread safe because it does nothing.

Comment: `createFactoryClass()` appears to be thread safe too.  As you say you init the map once then never write it again.  The proviso here is that it still must be made visible; assigning it to `final` is fine and makes the map (and all writes) visible, just like `volatile` would and `synchronized` would.  C.f. ["Safe Publication"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are always thread-safe, unless the variable is a reference to an object which is shared, i.e. like in the following example:

```
static void setValue(Example obj, int val) {
    obj.val = val;
}

Example sharedObj = ...;

new Thread(() -> { setValue(sharedObj, 1); }).start();
new Thread(() -> { setValue(sharedObj, 2); }).start();
```

In that example, though, it's not the use of the reference to `sharedObj` per se which is unsafe, it's the fact that we used that reference to change the state of `sharedObj.val` concurrently.

If instead we had two threads which have references to different objects:

```
Thread threadA = new Thread(() -> {
    Example objA = ...;
    setValue(objA, 1);
});
Thread threadB = new Thread(() -> {
    Example objB = ...;
    setValue(objB, 2);
});
threadA.start();
threadB.start();
```

The JVM won't get confused and pass e.g. `threadA`'s object to `threadB`'s invocation of `setValue`, or vice-versa. That's kind of what it sounds like you are asking, and that won't happen. Every thread has its own call stack and each thread's invocation of `setValue` opens a new stack frame on its own thread. In other words, `threadA` calls `setValue` which creates a stack frame on `threadA` with its own local variables, and `threadB` calls `setValue` which creates a stack frame on `threadB` with its own local variables.

There is a separate concern which is that the changes your `init` method makes may not be seen by other threads. For example, say you have a `Thread thread1` whose job it is to initialize objects by passing them to `init`, and then pass those objects to some other `Thread thread2`. Will `thread2` see the changes which `init` made to the objects on `thread1`? The answer is *no*, without some sort of memory synchronization, `thread2` may not see the changes which were made during `thread1`'s call to `init`.

Making `myMethod` synchronized probably doesn't solve that problem, though. Instead, `thread1` and `thread2` need some way to communicate, like a shared monitor object or lock.

There's a third issue which I guess you are hinting at, which is about the initialization of the map. If the map is built only during a static initializer, then it's thread-safe, because [class initialization is performed under synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) and:

> *An implementation may optimize this procedure by eliding the lock acquisition [...] when it can determine that the initialization of the class has already completed, provided that, in terms of the memory model, all happens-before orderings that would exist if the lock were acquired, still exist when the optimization is performed.*

In other words, static initialization is guaranteed to be seen by other threads, even if the JVM decides that it's been awhile since a particular class has been initialized and decides to read the field without trying to acquire the initialization lock.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest different naming for the classes/methods, as currently it is difficult to understand what is going on. Also I would make the factories into singletons.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class FactoryStore {

private static final Map<String, AbstractFactory> FACTORIES = new HashMap<>();

static {
    FACTORIES.put("a", FactoryA.getInstance());
    FACTORIES.put("b", FactoryB.getInstance());
}

public static Object createObject(String factoryName, Object parameters) {
    return FACTORIES.get(factoryName).createNewObject(parameters);
}
}



 abstract class AbstractFactory {

Object createNewObject(Object parameters) {
    // not thread-safe stuff
    return new Object();
}


 }



class FactoryA extends AbstractFactory {

private static final FactoryA instance = new FactoryA();

private FactoryA() {
    // thread safe stuff
}

public static FactoryA getInstance() {
    return instance;
}


 }


 class FactoryB extends AbstractFactory {

private static final FactoryB instance = new FactoryB();

 private FactoryB() {
    // thread safe stuff
}

public static FactoryB getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
synchronized Object createNewObject(Object obj) {
     // can override object creation; this is thread-safe thanks to keyword
    return new Object();
}

 }
```