# bill pugh singleton, why thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Why is Bill Pugh's  Singleton design pattern thread safe?

```
public class Logger {
    private Logger() {
        // private constructor
    }

    // static inner class - inner classes are not loaded until they are
    // referenced.
    private static class LoggerHolder {
        private static Logger logger = new Logger();
    }

    // global access point
    public static Logger getInstance() {
        return LoggerHolder.logger;
    }

    //Other methods
}
```

Comment: Your answer is within comments itself

Comment: Because the semantic for loading and initializing classes is defined in a way that it is only done once and the static final fields are published safely.

Comment: Brian Goetz explains this best.  You should read his book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) for the full explanation.  For the abridged version, see this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  (But basically, the `static` keyword is special in Java, and implies a *happens-before* edge due to the way Java classes are loaded and initialized.)

Comment: @AndyTurner Both `final` and `static` do.  It's one or the other, it doesn't need to be `final`.  Didn't double check but I'm sure that's in Brian Goetz's book.  Please check it again!

Answer (score 6):

Lets take a look at the comments:

> // static inner class - inner classes are not loaded until they are referenced.

The **"loading"** is the process of **initialising** the inner  class (LoggerHolder).

**"until they are referenced"** means the inner class (LoggerHolder) is not initialised until the LoggerHolder.logger static field is referenced ("used somewhere") in this case.

So the call to **getInstance()** references **LoggerHolder.logger** and starts the initialisation of the **LoggerHolder** inner class.

The whole process of initialising a class is **synchronised by the JVM**.

From the [relevant documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization
> of a class or interface requires careful synchronization

> The implementation of
> the Java Virtual Machine is responsible for taking care of
> synchronization and recursive initialization

The initialisation of the static field:

```
private static Logger logger = new Logger();
```

is a part of the inner class initialisation and this whole initialisation process ("loading") is effectively synchronised by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of definition of 'static' in java, the inner class and the inner
Object (logger in this case) load once with the class loader by jvm.

I think its better to define the logger object as final.
Second or other threads cannot instantiate the object again!