# Thread safe unique number generator

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

How to implement java thread-safe generator of unique numbers? 
This is my version

```
public class Generator {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Generator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    public Integer generate() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

But theoretically, when shuffling can get a unique number. How to achieve uniqueness? Do I need to sync across my collection when I shuffle, i.e.

```
synchronized (list) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not unique.  `get(0)` might return the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues here, Safe Publication and then the subsequent thread safety of the mutate (`shuffle()`) followed by a read (`get(0)`).

I don't think your code address safe publication at all.  Use `volatile` or `final` for that, and for `volatile` do the assignment last in the ctor.

```
public class Generator {
    private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Generator() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
```

Or

```
public class Generator {
    private volatile List<Integer> list; 

    public Generator() {
        List<Integer> temp = = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            temp.add(i);
        }
        list = temp;
    }
```

Now I think you can synchronize on `list` (or any other object) to get thread safety.  You have to make sure the `get` is inside the synchronized block.  Note that your code has a bug and doesn't actually produce unique numbers.

```
public Integer generate() {
  synchronized( list ) {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list.get(0);
  }
}
```

Or

```
public synchronized Integer generate() {
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list.get(0);
}
```

See Brian Goetz *Java Concurrency in Practice* for more, esp. Safe Publication.  SO has a short [discussion of the Safe Publication pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801993/java-multi-threading-safe-publication) too.

Getting unique numbers is just logic, not related to thread safety.  First shuffle only once in the ctor, then just increment a counter to return numbers in order.  Remember your list only has 1000 numbers so you can return at most 1000 unique numbers.

```
private int index;
public synchronized Integer generate() {
    if( index >= 1000 ) throw IllegalArgumentError();
    return list.get( index++ );
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, kudos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know, that this generator can return not unique number, how can i achieve uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here (sorry if off base), that you're looking for a random number between 0 <= x < 1000:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000);
```

Comment: Need to create generator without using Random and ThreadLocalRandom.

Comment: ...Collections.shuffle() uses random

Comment: @NotaJD , will it be unique if I spawn different thread at the same second to get the value?