# Options for informing a Thread to stop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to inform a so-called worker thread to stop work at the next available oppertunity.  Currently I'm using something like this:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        while (!StopRequested)
            DoWork();
    }
```

The concern I have is that StopRequested is being set to True on a different thread.  Is this safe? I know I can't lock a boolean.  Perhaps there's a different way to inform a thread that a stop is required.  For example I would be happy to check `Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.StopRequested`  but it's not clear how I can set the thread state as such.

Comment: Why can't you lock around a boolean?  It's generally considered good practice to create a separate `Object` for any locks, anyhow.

Comment: I can't lock the bool because its' a value type -- I could create an so-called sync object for no other purpose than to lock it when getting/setting the bool flag --- but it seems to me that locks on a bool should be safe, and at least Reed Copsey agrees

Comment: Yeah, locking around a bool should be safe.  Cooperative cancellation.  the Backgroundworker supports a similar concept if it's appropriate to the task you're performing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a better approach than trying to set the ThreadState.  If you look at the docs for [ThreadState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx), it specifically says that StopRequested is for internal use only.

Setting a boolean from another thread is a safe operation.  You shouldn't need to lock in this case.

Comment: I'd like to read more about this approach. Do you have links to similar questions, papers, blogs?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the work for you, using `RunWorkerAsync()` and handling the `worker.CancellationPending == true` case during your logic.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.DoWork += MyWorkFunction;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += MyWorkDoneSuccessfullyFunction;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Another solution would be to use a volatile bool to signal that you need to stop, which you could set anywhere within the class.

```
private volatile bool cancelWork = false;

public void CancelWork()
{
  cancelWork = true;
}
```

Comment: e.Cancelled is only after the worker has been stopped, see my post below

Comment: @SwDevMan81: You're correct, editted that comment. A correct implementation for DoWork can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using Event object will be better probably. Especially if your thread blocks. (Then you can still wait for the event inside the blocking call)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Thread.Abort() and wrap any necessary cleanup in the DoWork() method in a finally block.

Answer (score 1):

> The concern I have is that
>   StopRequested is being set to True on
>   a different thread. Is this safe?

You should make sure that the `StopRequested` field has the [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28VS.71%29.aspx) keyword. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782912/primitive-synchronization-primitives-safe/783911#783911) for the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), you would call the [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx) function of the BackgroundWorker sets the [CancellationPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx) Property to true, which is what you would look for in your loop:

```
public void Run(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)   
{      
   BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
   if(worker != null)
   {
      while (!worker.CancellationPending)   
      {
         DoWork();  
      }
   }
}
```

The above would be the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event code which is called when you run the [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync.aspx) function.